# SQL Server is not reachable at random

Tags: sql-server, windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2019

A little background about situation. I am using SQL Server 2019 Express installed on a Windows Server 2019. The thing is that at random times I can't reach SQL Server only from one specific server which is a Windows Server 2008R2 using SSMS tool.

But I am able to connect via RDP to this server at that time, server seems working fine from first view. From all other servers, workstations and locally I am able to connect to SQL during that not-working period.

I am connecting to server via hostname, ping resolves to IP seems good.

What I tried so far:

- checked maximum connections which is unlimited
- Firewall port 1433 is open
- I check if backup occurring at that time and this maybe causing the problem but backup is not the case.

Since the problem occurs at random I'm not sure how to collect constant logs such as network like from Wireshark. It feels like for now Wireshark could give me a big log file to analyze so I don't want to use this.

Is there a way to identify from logs or so on why such problem occurs during time to time? Should I be worried about Windows server 2008? Or should I check something else?

Comment: What's the actual error you get? What authentication method are you using, Windows or SQL? Integrated authentication is dependent on whether or not Kerberos and the domain controllers are feeling generous, which is beyond SQL Server's control. Also, since this an Express instance, are you accessing it through an instance name (`host\sqlexpress`)? The latter also requires the SQL Server Browser server is reachable through UDP on port 1434 (and UDP being unreliable could have an impact).

Comment: It's Microsoft SQL server error:53. Again, ping is working fine, connecting from other machines to the same SQL I can without any issues. Authentication method is used Windows here. BTW, servers are domain joined, just to be clear. additionally, I added  firewall rule 1434 UDP, see if this helps...

Comment: That is not a SQL Server error but a Windows error -- `ERROR_BAD_NETPATH`, "the network path was not found". I don't know under what circumstances you can get that while ping still works. It's likely not a SQL Server specific problem, though, since all this happens before a connection is even made.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-53-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Same difference -- SQL Server (as in, the remote server) isn't generating this error, this is a client-side error generating in the driver presented as though it came from the server. You can check the server error logs to see if there are any details (`sp_readerrorlog` if you can't access the files directly), but I suspect you won't find any -- the server probably doesn't even see a connection attempt.

Comment: That's the thing. I don't see any connection attempts in the logs. Still wondering what can cause this issue. At least how to identify it.

Comment: At the core it means there's something wrong on the network -- intermittent DNS failure, packet loss, a virtual machine not getting a time slice. As to what exactly it is, neither SQL Server nor the client drivers are going to tell you. The standard approaches for troubleshooting network connectivity apply; that may indeed mean breaking out a packet sniffer. It is in any case not a programming related question.

Comment: OK, thanks for sharing a thoughtful comments.

Comment: @JeroenMostert different protocols can follow different routes across a network, e.g.: ICMP might work fine for pinging servers but UDP traffic could be routed differently or even dropped on the floor by a loaded router with higher priorities to manage.

Comment: As JeroenMostert mentioned, connecting via instance names requires that the SQL Browser service is running on the target server and is reachable via udp/1434 (to resolve the instance name to a TCP port number) before the client can even connect to the TCP port that the SQL Server is listening on. If you're not even seeing connection attempts/failures in the ERRORLOG file it suggests that this instance name resolution process is failing. Try connecting to the port number directly, e.g.: if the server is listening on port 1433 then instead of `ServerName\MSSQLSERVER` try `ServerName,1433`.